# What is this wire-controlled camera?

Tags: equipment-identification

I could only see a silhouette of the following video camera:

[image]

The body seems too small to be an ordinary camera, so it seems to be some kind of wire-controlled video camera.

Note that most POV cameras have connectors on the back, but this one has connectors on the sides, so that should narrow it down.

Comment: Given the proximity to a computer keyboard, I would guess a somewhat higher than entry-level webcam...

Comment: Calls for speculation. Keeping in mind that video questions and requests for resources are off topic, consider editing to focus on the thing that motivates your question. Are you trying to find a small camera? Do you need to take photos by remote control?

Comment: @Caleb It is only "speculation" for somebody with no experience with the camera in question. If somebody showed me a silhouette of a camera I use, I would recognize it instantly. Just because the question is "speculation" for you, don't assume there is noone who can recognize this camera from the outline of its body, lens and cables alone.

Comment: @ClicketyRicket The point is: Can you rephrase the question in a way that makes it relevant to photography rather than video? And can you make it useful to future readers rather than just yourself?

Comment: What is the source of the image? Is this a capture from a video, such as TV show or movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a BlackMagic Design Micro Cine Camera.  The BMMCC is equipped for full remote operation over sBUS, LANC or PWM and this allows control of all lens and camera functions.

Comment: It is definitely similar to that, however, this camera seems to have a jack in the center left side and one right below it (judging from the cable positions), but the Black Magic has only a single mic jack which is near the TOP of the left side, so it would seem to be different, or possibly it is an older model of the Black Magic you listed.

Comment: it might be the 4k version that does have 4 ports on the left side. see this picture http://cdn.studiodaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bmd-micro-studio-4k.jpg